# Grammatical function of comparatives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparative

Can we consider comparative form of adjectives as adjectives, grammatically? I mean, in the following sentence, is "thinner" an adjective?

> "*You look thinner*."

Comment: There is an implied comparison: "You look thinner (compared to last time)". "He is grumpier (from when you/I last saw him)"

Comment: A word's function is different from its lexical category. Nothing can ever function as an adjective (although something could function in the same way an adjective does; e.g. a noun could function in the same way an adjective does in certain constructions, but there's just no reason to put it that way because that confuses function and category; it's better to simply name the function it performs). The function of the *thinner* in your sentence is different from its function in *Call the thinner man in first*, which says nothing about the word's lexical category.

Comment: I agree with @userr2684291 "Thinner" belongs to the category **adjective**, and to the function **complement**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a comparative adjective. You can use it before a noun too, as in
"Call the thinner man in first."
The same applies to superlative adjectives.